# Scope validation failed introspection (sporadic)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver3, identityserver4

At the moment I have deployed my Identityserver project on an Azure instance.
Some test users reported some problems. And I checked the logs:

```
2016-11-26 11:02:36.543 ERROR Scope validation failed. 
2016-11-26 11:02:36.578 ERROR Scope unauthorized to call introspection endpoint. aborting. 
2016-11-26 11:02:36.970 ERROR Scope validation failed. 
2016-11-26 11:02:37.016 ERROR Scope unauthorized to call introspection endpoint. aborting.
```

This happens rougly every hour a couple of times. I myself didn't had this problem on my localmachine or on the Azure platform.

Does someone have an idea where I can search looking. I'm using the Hybrid flow MVC application (From the docs).

When does the introspection endpoint gets called?

[Information](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/introspection.html)

I understand this, but where exactly does the MVC application do this call? 
Is it at the startup? (app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication()) or when you place the [Auhtorization] attribute on an action method?

Comment: Introspection is called when the token is not a JWT. That's determined by looking for any dots "." in the token. Perhaps someone is simply spamming your API with junk for the authorization header?

Comment: @BrockAllen Thx for your reponse! I'll investigate this matter. Have a nice day.